# Destructuring objects as function parameters deep extend

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to "deep extend" objects when using destructuring to set default properties of an object passed into a function?

Example:

```js
function foo({
  foo = 'foo',
  bar = 'bar',
  baz = {
    propA: 'propA',
    propB: 'propB'
  }
} = {}) {
  console.log(foo);
  console.log(bar);
  console.log(baz);
}

foo({
  foo: 'changed',
  baz: {
    propA: 'changed'
  }
});
```

This outputs: (baz is overwrote)

```
changed
bar
{
  "propA": "changed"
}
```

Is there syntax which will extend the `baz` object, to give output:

```
changed
bar
{
  "propA": "changed",
  "propB": "propB"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no native-way to do what you ask, but you can write your own `function decorator`, of course it is a verbose approach...

Note: In order to perform a **deep merge** you should use some of the existing solution developed by the community, both `Object.assign` and `Object Spread Operator` perform a shallow copy of the source, even, writing your own deepmerge function could be error-prone. I suggest you to use [`lodash#merge`](https://lodash.com/docs/#merge) that is commonly accepted as one of the solid solutions to the problem.

```js
var {
  // https://lodash.com/docs/#merge
  merge
} = require('lodash');

function defaultsArgDecorator(defaults, target) {

  return function(args) {
    
    return target(
      merge(Object.create(defaults), args)
    )
  }
}


function _foo(args) { console.log({args}); }
var foo = defaultsArgDecorator({
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar',
  baz: {
    propA: 'propA',
    propB: 'propB'
  }
}, _foo);

foo({bar: "ciao bello", baz: {propA: "HELLO"}})
```

Answer (score 5):

Since parameters destructuring allow you to use previous parameters in the defaults of other parameters, you can create a property that doesn't exit on the original parameters, for example `__baz`, and set its defaults using `baz`. 
In the method you'll use `__baz` instead of `baz`.

> Note: this is a hack, and if the object contains a property by the
>   name of `__baz` it will override the default, with unexpected results.
>   However, you can name the default property with something like
>   `dontUse__baz`, which has a very low chance of being used.

**Default properties using [`Object#assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):**

```js
function foo({
  foo = 'foo',
    bar = 'bar',
    baz,
    __baz = Object.assign({  
      "propA": "changed",
      "propB": "propB"
    }, baz)
} = {}) {
  console.log(foo);
  console.log(bar);
  console.log(__baz);
}

foo({
  foo: 'changed',
  baz: {
    propA: 'changed'
  }
});
```

---

**Default properties using [object spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) (requires babel plugin - [see link](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)):**

```js
function foo({
  foo = 'foo',
    bar = 'bar',
    baz,
    __baz = {  
      "propA": "changed",
      "propB": "propB",
      ...baz
    }
} = {}) {
  console.log(foo);
  console.log(bar);
  console.log(__baz);
}

foo({
  foo: 'changed',
  baz: {
    propA: 'changed'
  }
});
```

Comment: I didn't think of that second one, nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do nested destructuring. You destructure baz, but also destructure `propA` and `propB`.

If you need your object whole and don't want to 'rebuild' it, this isn't for you, but it does accomplish one objective of setting default values for unspecified properties nested in an object.

I've left `baz` as a separate descructured value in addition to it's properties as an example of a sometimes handy pattern, but you would most likely want to remove it since it suffers from the same problem of losing default properties.

```js
function foo({
  foo = 'foo',
  bar = 'bar', 
  baz,  // likely extraneous and confusing, here for example
  baz: { propA = 'propA', propB = 'propB' }
} = {}) {
  console.log(foo);
  console.log(bar);
  console.log(propA, propB);
  console.log(baz);
  console.log(Object.assign(baz, {propA, propB}));
}

foo({
  foo: 'changed',
  baz: {
    propA: 'changed'
  }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Yep, totally possible!

Solution 1:

```
function foo({
  foo = 'foo',
  bar = 'bar',
  baz: {
    propA = 'propA',
    propB = 'propB'
  } = {}
}) {
  console.log(foo)
  console.log(bar)
  console.log({propA, propB}) // Because `bar` is renamed to `{propA, propB}`. Hence, no local variable named `baz`
}
```

Solution 2 (Workaround):

```
function foo({
  foo = 'foo',
  bar = 'bar',
  baz = {}
}) {
  // ...
  const baz2 = Object.assign({}, {propA: 'propA', propB: 'propB'} = {})
  console.log(baz2) // Yeah, not really a solution
}
```

You can even do this:

```
const func = ([{foo, bar: {a, b: BB, c: CC = 'c'} = {}} = {}], ...{0: rest0 = 0, 1: rest1 = '1'}) => { /* do stuffs */ }
```

The code above is a complicated example, I'll use simpler examples to explain:

Example 1:

```
const f1 = ({x: varx}) => console.log(varx)
```

When you call `f1(obj)`, `obj.x` will be assigned to `varx` in `f1`'s scope

Example 2:

```
const f2 = ({xy: {x, y}}) => console.log({x, y})
```

Similar to `f1` but with `{x, y}` in place of `varx`, `obj.xy` will be assigned to `{x, y}`, so `x = obj.xy.x` and `y = obj.xy.y`

Example 3: Now let add create default parameters

```
const f3 = ({xy: {x, y} = {}}) => { /* do stuffs */ }
```

Now, you still have to pass `obj` as an object but you no longer have to provide `obj.xy`. If `obj.xy` is `undefined`, `x` and `y` are `undefined`s

Example 4: Now, let `x` and `y` have default values

```
const f4 = ({xy: {x = 'XXX', y = 'YYY'} = {}}) => { /* do stuffs */ }
```

If `obj.xy` you passed is `undefined`, `{x, y}` will be set to `{x: undefined, y: undefined}`, but since `x` and `y` also have default values, `x` will be `'XXX'` and `y` will be `'YYY'`

Example 4: "THE ULTIMATE LIFE FORM"

```
const f5 = ({xy: {x = 'XXX', y = 'YYY'} = {}} = {}) => { /* do stuffs */ }
```

Guess I don't have to explain this anymore :D

Comment: @Hitmands there's no such concept as `Object spread operator`, Arrays in JS are Objects

Comment: @DMaster Yes there is, and you are using it above. Arrays are objects, but Objects are not Arrays. `...{}` is the [object-rest-spread](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) proposal

Comment: @Hitmands Objects are not Arrays but it doesn't mean that you cannot "destructure" an array as an object because arrays are objects (you can even do it with string, number, etc but not `null` and `undefined`). When you do `...rest`, `rest` will automatically be an array

Comment: Nethier `baz: {  propA = 'propA',  propB = 'propB'  } = {}` (compile error) or `baz = {   propA = 'propA',   propB = 'propB'  } = {}` (baz is overwritten) work for me

Comment: @DMaster **you cannot spread** over objects, because the operator is **Array spread operator**, there is a proposal called **object-spread-operator** as wrote by @CodingIntrigue... by the way, even the `Object spread operator` performs a shallow copy of the source... I think you need to have a look at the specification.

Comment: @Hitmands Oh! I missed your "Array spread operator"! I think you're assuming that all `...` are the same. They're not the same though. This is a true **array spread operator**: `[a, b, c, ...def]`; And this is a "not-array-spread-operator" a.k.a **rest parameters**: `function fn (a, b, c, ...def) {}`; See? Totally different!

Comment: @Hitmands Also, I can tell you that I'm not using nor confusing with "object spread operator" which is available in Python 3. And it's not and shouldn't be `[...{}]` nor `function (...{}) {}` but `{...obj}`, I believe you see my point

Comment: AH, ok, you are just confusing the language, we are talking about `JAVASCRIPT`.

Comment: I said that "object spread operator" available in Python 3 to prove that I knew it, ok? I'm not confusing!

Comment: @DMaster I pasted your code into the [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20func%20%3D%20(%5B%7Bfoo%2C%20bar%3A%20%7Ba%2C%20b%3A%20BB%2C%20c%3A%20CC%20%3D%20'c'%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%5D%2C%20...%7B0%3A%20rest0%20%3D%200%2C%201%3A%20rest1%20%3D%20'1'%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%7D). Can you explain why I get an `Unexpected token` error?

Comment: @CodingIntrigue I tested my code in Node.js 6 prompt, you can test it again in browser console (press F12). Babel is just a tool to convert es6 code into es5 so developers can enjoy es6 syntactic sugars